# Swift Warnings after installing iOS AWS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting the following warnings after installing the iOS AWS SDK, I did some research and it seems this is a common issue.
Wanted to see if any updates on how to fix??

[image]

Comment: the only thing you can do is report this issue to Amazon (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues). It's pretty harmless though: it means that one of the switch cases should have `@unknown default` and it doesn't. The `@unknown default` is only needed if they change set of values, but forget to change the switch. Not your concern

Comment: ok Thank you Kiril!